# Listing directories with a specific one first

Tags: bash, unix

Is it possible in unix shell to get all folders, starting with specific one? For example I have folder1 and folder2, after I use "tree" I get them both like: folder1, folder2. But I want to get: folder2, folder1. ( in a different sequence)

Comment: What kind of 'different sequence'? Alphabetical? Reverse Alphabetical? Please explain better what do you want to achieve

Comment: What order do you want them in? It's not clear from your two-item example.

Comment: If the *only* thing you want to change is putting a specific item first, but otherwise keeping collation locale order, that's straightforward enough (though the details depend on knowing exactly which shell you're using, and the question presently doesn't specify).

Comment: It would also be helpful to have a bit more context. Do you want to iterate over these items with a loop (so it'd be helpful to collect them in an array)? Do you want to pass them on an argument list?

Comment: Ubuntu terminal. The order is not very important. I just want to start with an exact folder, but display others as well. Names may not me similar.

Comment: Is the one you want to start with first named in a variable? Does the code need to correctly handle the case where the entry named in that variable doesn't exist?

Comment: And again, **which specific shell**? bash? ash? dash? ksh? zsh? The terminal makes no difference to what syntax is allowed; the shell makes *all* the difference.

Comment: Bash. Code may not. I know that the one I'm looking for exists.

Comment: I've tried to edit to make the title more specific. "A different sequence" doesn't really say anything about what that sequence is, other than that it's different, but since you actually *know* what the difference you want is, better to describe that. (And "folder" is Windows terminology; on UNIX, we call them "directories").

Answer (score 0):

Silly but working (in bash or ksh93):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

[[ -d $1 ]] || { echo "Usage: ${0##*/} first-directory" >&2; exit 1; }
first_directory=$1

all_directories=( */ )
all_directories=( "${all_directories[@]%/}" )
printf '%q\n' "$first_directory"
for directory in "${all_directories[@]}"; do
  [[ $directory = "$first_directory" ]] && continue
  printf '%q\n' "$directory"
done
```

Note that we're printing directories in `eval`-safe form, which guarantees that they're one-per-line. Because filenames on UNIX can contain literal newlines, printing literal names is unsafe unless NUL delimiters (which *cannot* exist in names) are used.